# Excel - Increment number while retaining cell string/text

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to increment only the number part (001) of a cell as i have to copy almost the same info to hundreds of cells.

htt://localhost/tins/csv_img_uploads/TFS_Jan_20018_**001**.jpg,htt://localhost/tins/csv_img_uploads/TFS_Jan_20018_**001**_zoom.jpg

I think part of the formula is something like:

="http://localhost/tins/csv_img_uploads/TFS_Jan_20018_"&ROWS(J$155:J155)&":"

Any idea?

[Screen grab from my excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGbLA.png)

Comment: Unable to find the Part number you are trying to increment !!!

Comment: (1) What are you doing to get the formula in cell `J115` to be displayed *as a formula* (with a `=` at the beginning) rather than as a computed value?  Were you in the middle of typing into that cell when you made the screen grab?  What happens when you press “Enter”, or otherwise evaluate the formula?  (2) Why does your formula end with `":"` instead of `".jpg"`?  (3) Just out of curiosity, do you really mean “Jan_20018”?

Comment: im trying to get the next cell to say: htt://localhost/tins/csv_img_uploads/TFS_Jan_20018_002.jpg,htt://localhost/tins/csv_img_uploads/TFS_Jan_20018_002_zoom.jpg

Comment: ie just roll the 001 part to 002 then 003 and so on. so i dont have manually edit 300 cells individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a helper column. In the example below, I took your url and referenced my helper column (Col D). Then, you can just fill the series in the helper column and even hide it if you want.

Formulas in Col C read:

```
="http://localhost/tins/csv_img_uploads/TFS_Jan_20018_"&(D1)&".jpeg,http://localhost/tins/csv_img_uploads/TFS_Jan_20018_"&(D1)&"_zoom.jpg"
```

Enter your formula in the first row, then drag down to fill the series by hovering over the lower right corner of the cell until the cursor changes to a "+" symbol. Or, if your data is in a table, it should autofill the series.

Col D is formatted as "text", so it shows the actual digits you want to display, instead of changing "0001" to the number "1".

Hope this helps!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot, it appears you just need one wee bit of extra for the formula (assuming you correct the other likely difficulties:  the "20018" likely should have just one zero (trivial) and the ":" and onwards after the ROWS() function looks to need a bit added).

ROWS(), as you are using it will produce the number series for you, of course. It's perfect as is and perfect for that purpose. However, it will produce "1" and "2" and so on, not "001" and "002" and so on.

So "wrap it" in a TEXT() function and specify "000" as the number format it should return. Then you will get "001" and so on.

At that point, it should work perfectly.

More generally, for how this comes up, one has some alphanumeric part number, maybe even obtuse like "AN34TDKH020" and needs to increment one or both numerical portions. The key then is "Is the pattern well behaved?" Do the first two characters remain the same? Is the second alpha portion always four characters and not sometimes two or eight? If that portion DOES move about on you, is the rest stable? As in that portion always starts at the 5th character and the final numerical part is always three digits long?

Look for pattern stabilities like that, then apply LEFT(), MID(), and RIGHT() as needed to first pull out the portion you want to increment, increment it, put it back together and continue for any other portions until done incrementing and then stop, giving you the incremented result. Whatif can be applied as well as simple +1, +1, etc.

Given that letter characters have numerical values to computers (remember your CHAR() function), one can even increment letters n many circumstances though those often have meanings in part numbers that make incrementing, as such, a worthless endeavor.

But yours is ready to go after you wrap it in the TEXT() function:  TEXT(ROWS(J$115:J115),"000") .